# Does the catch unit test framework support junit-style test reports?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

Planning to switch over to the [Catch unit test framework for c++](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch).

I need the test results to be in junit report format and I just want to confirm if it has that capability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does.

You can generate a JUnit compatible XML report via adding

```
-r junit
```

to the command line of your compiled Catch test suite (cf. [Integration with build systems](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/build-systems.md#junit-reporter)).

Answer (score 1):

A small amount of [reading](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/why-catch.md) reveals:

> **Other core features**
>
> JUnit xml output is supported for integration with third-party tools, such as CI servers.

Comment: As @maxschlepzig points out, Catch supports JUnit with `-r junit` now.